# Weird Ruby class initialization logic?

Tags: ruby, constructor

Some open source code I'm integrating in my application has some classes that include code to that effect:

```
class SomeClass < SomeParentClass

  def self.new(options = {})
    super().tap { |o|
      # do something with `o` according to `options`
    }
  end

  def initialize(options = {})
    # initialize some data according to `options`
  end

end
```

As far as I understand, both `self.new` and `initialize` do the same thing - the latter one "during construction" and the former one "after construction", and it looks to me like a horrible pattern to use - why split up the object initialization into two parts where one is obviously "The Wrong Think(tm)"?

Comment: _"Some open source code has code"_  – would you mind sharing a link?

Comment: Sorry, @sawa edited my question to read differently than what I intended. I reverted it back now, I hope it makes more sense. Regarding your specific question - I rather not: I express my opinion here that this is a bad code but I have no intention of disparaging specific authors.

Comment: @Guss I understand your intention, but you can hardly explain "why" something was implemented in a specific way without seeing the implementation.

Comment: @Stefan - apparently the example is taken from very old code that is not in use anymore: when tracing some code I didn't notice that my IDE loaded an old gem that was installed on my system instead of the current one in the bundle. The project in question is Punchblock which removed the problematic code in [this commit](https://github.com/adhearsion/punchblock/commit/92b19f4f3633ea1955fc5dff9b67616776350060). The use case, [as explained here](https://github.com/adhearsion/punchblock/blob/70a647d2d35f2b456f35d7e4394ed406b1732d83/lib/punchblock/protocol/ozone/accept.rb) is to enforce "post init"

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, I'd like to see what is inside the `super().tap { |o|` block, because although this looks like bad practice, just maybe there is some interaction required before or after `initialize` is called.

Without context, it is possible that you are just looking at something that works but is not considered good practice in Ruby.

However, maybe the approach of separate `self.new` and `initialize` methods allows the framework designer to implement a subclass-able part of the framework and still ensure setup required for the framework is completed without slightly awkward documentation that requires a specific use of `super()`. It would be a slightly easier to document and cleaner-looking API if the end user gets functionality they expect with just the subclass `class MyClass < FrameworkClass` and without some additional note like:

> When you implement the subclass `initialize`, remember to put `super` at the start, otherwise the magic won't work

. . . personally I'd find that design questionable, but I think there would at least be a clear motivation.

There might be deeper Ruby language reasons to have code run in a custom `self.new` block - for instance it may allow constructor to switch or alter the specific object (even returning an object of a different class) before returning it. However, I have very rarely seen such things done in practice, there is nearly always some other way of achieving the goals of such code without customising `new`.

---

Examples of custom/different `Class.new` methods raised in the comments:

- [Struct.new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html#method-c-new) which can optionally take a class name and return objects of that dynamically created class.
- [In-table inheritance for ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/268a5bb010ef91880d9b03b60e5e86ae5521e73c/activerecord/test/models/bulb.rb), which allows end user to load an object of unknown class from a table and receive the right object.

The latter one could possibly be avoided with a different ORM design for inheritance (although all such schemes have pros/cons).

The first one (Structs) is core to the language, so has to work like that now (although the designers *could* have chosen a different method name).

Comment: You would only have to call `super` if you override `initialize`.

Comment: @NeilSlater - a) the example is complete except for the code inside the `tap` block - that happens after the initialize has completed. b) It's 95% of time doing things like `o[:somekey] = options[:somekey]` (`SomeParentClass` has `[]` delegates to an internal dictionary).

Comment: OK, if I understand your possible reasoning correctly, a custom `new` method can apply logic "before entering" child `initialize` and "after exit" child initialize, better controller for the initialization order than what a custom `initialize` can do - whose execution order is determined by the child. So if I want to make sure that a child cannot override the value of some property, I set it in the "after exit" of the child's `initialize`. a "poor-man's aspect programming" thing. I feel this is still a horrible way to design APIs - a parent class shouldnt prevent a child from overriding things

Comment: @Guss: I would agree it is horrible, I am just searching for a motivation.

Comment: @Stefan: yes that's what I am getting at - perhaps the customisation allowed requires or is open to the framework user providing their own `initialize` method, and the designer prefers to make the framework support for this more magical with less boilerplate code required.

Comment: Chances are the _"remember to call `super`"_ part was already covered in the user's first OOP tutorial ;-)

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/268a5bb010ef91880d9b03b60e5e86ae5521e73c/activerecord/test/models/bulb.rb is an example of returning objects of a different class from `self.new`

Comment: @fylooi: Yes that's an in-table inheritance for ORM. I think there are probably a few alternative approaches that don't overload `.new`, but they would either require a lot more work or better support in the core library.

Comment: "There might be […] reasons to have code run in a custom `self.new` block - for instance it may allow constructor to […] alter the specific object (even returning an object of a different class) […]. However, I have never seen such things done in practice," – I have: `Struct::new` returns a `Class` instead of a `Struct`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I've very rarely used Structs. Looks like it is implemented directly at the method binding (in the C API) as opposed to overloading `new` using the Ruby language.

Comment: @NeilSlater: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/struct.rb#L8-L53 I'm also pretty sure that neither JRuby, nor IronRuby, nor MagLev, nor Opal implement it using the C API, since they don't even *have* a C API.

Comment: It seems all examples, including the original one (see comment on the question) are about marshaling - which is always a process of translating between different designs and thus usually calls for some grimy code...

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Well, now you have made me see it I have to amend my experience from "never" to "very rarely"

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e56c9ef08db49653f0c63a0305d563b2514b266b is another interesting use case: allowing a decorator to not decorate certain objects.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to tell why that code is there without seeing the rest of the code.

However, there is something in your question I want to address:

> As far as I understand, both `self.new` and `initialize` do the same thing - the latter one "during construction" and the former one "after construction"

They do not do the same thing.

Object construction in Ruby is performed in two steps: [`Class#allocate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-allocate) allocates a new empty object from the object space and sets its internal class pointer to `self`. Then, you initialize the empty object with some default values. Customarily, this initialization is performed by a method called `initialize`, but that is just a convention; the method can be called anything you like.

There is an additional helper method called [`Class#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) which does nothing but perform the two steps in sequence, for the programmer's convenience:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)
    obj
  end

  def allocate
    obj = __MagicVM__.__allocate_an_empty_object_from_the_object_space__
    obj.__set_internal_class_pointer__(self)
    obj
  end
end

class BasicObject
  private def initialize(*) end
end
```

Comment: I think "Customarily," doesn't give enough strength to the convention - it is pretty rare to do things differently, and most guides/tutorials to the language don't even consider it. Of course there isn't a formal language specification, so you cannot say that needing `initialize` or even `new` is required by the language, but these are highly standardised across Ruby core and standard library.

Comment: I used this wording specifically to *de-emphasize* the convention. Of course, it is a strong convention (and the only one), and anybody who does something different, in in for a world of pain (and ridicule), but it is *not* part of the language semantics. There are plenty of answers here on [so], for example, that claim that there is some language magic that automagically re-writes calls to `::new` into calls to `#initialize`, when reality couldn't be much simpler: it's just one method calling another method.

Comment: The only thing "magic" is the *inside* of the method body of `Class#allocate` which can not be expressed in (portable) Ruby. You *can* write it in Ruby if you want (for example, the pseudo-implementation I showed), but at some point you have to call into some implementation-specific low-level API (which might very well also be written in Ruby, but the API is not part of the standard Ruby API). See the Klein VM for an example of a language VM written 100% in itself, including message dispatcher, garbage collector, memory allocator, JIT compiler, boot code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The **constructor** `new` has to be a *class method* since you start from where there is no instance; you can't be calling that method on a particular instance. On the other hand, an **initialization** routine `initialize` is better defined as an *instance method* because you want to do something specifically with a certain instance. Hence, Ruby is designed to internally call the instance method `initialize` on a new instance right after its creation by the class method `new`.

Comment: In the given code, the block argument `o` is that instance, so the block's code _could_ be moved into `initialize`.

Comment: @sawa - thanks, but I'm well aware of the Ruby semantics, as I've demonstrated in my question. I was asking for a possible explanation why someone would override the `new` *class method*.